# WordPress wp-admin/upload.php gives 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress

Actually I have a new WordPress Project.

When I open admin panel, All the Sections like Post , Pages , Appearance are all working fine. Except Media.

When I click on Media Link it gives 404 Page Error.

Secondly all the images are not showing in my WordPress site.

In WordPress Application, Woocommerce is also integrated but did not showing any product image and the path is coming correct.

Can anyone know , what is and where is the issue ??

Any help will be appreciating.

Thanks.

Comment: reupload the wordpress files?

Comment: why give me down vote ?? can you please explain ...

Comment: client tell me, it was working fine in morning time. but now it gives error by default.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort, you ask two questions in one (you should split those up), you give virtually no information and last, but not least, as long as your problem is not a result of your programming it is off topic for this site. Both questions might be better suited for [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 0):

Please give 777 Rights

```
/wp-content/uploads folder
```

Comment: Did not make any effect.

Comment: inner Folder give 777 right??
like 2015 folder or 2014